# Apps Script - Using Google Sheets REST API v4 - Values not being written - No error message

Tags: post, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I've got everything working, but the values are not being written to the spreadsheet.  I even get a partially valid response back from the POST request.  I just don't know where to put the `values`  I've tried putting them into the payload, and in the URL

```
function writeToSheet() {
  var id,options,range,response,sh,ss,url,values;

  id = 'Put the spreadsheet ID here';
  range = "Sheet1!A1:A1";
  values = "['3','two','nine']";

  url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" +
    id + "/values/" + range + ":append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED";

  options = {
    "method":"post",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    }
  }

  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options)
  response = JSON.parse(response);

  Logger.log('response ' + JSON.stringify(response))
}
```

I've tried:

```
url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" + id + 
  "/" + values + "/" + range + ":append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED";
```

I've tried putting a `values` property into the payload.  Nothing works.

My scopes are working fine.  I'm not getting any authorization errors.  This is my manifest file with the scopes that are working great.

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "webapp": {
    "access": "MYSELF",
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING"
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
                  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"]
}
```

I'm even getting a legitimate looking response back from the POST request, except for the values.

```
  /*  The response I'm getting back

  {
    "spreadsheetId":"ID Here",
    "tableRange":"Sheet1!A1:C2",
    "updates":{
      "spreadsheetId":"ID here",
      "updatedRange":"Sheet1!A3"
      }
  }

  */
```

Where to I put the values to write to the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- It is required to include `"application/json"` to the header.
- The request body is `{values: [['3','two','nine']]}`.

  - It supposes that you want to append the values of `'3','two','nine'` to column A, B and C, respectively.
  - If you want to append the values of `'3','two','nine'` to row 1, 2, and 3, respectively, please use `{values: [['3'],['two'],['nine']]}`.

#### Modified script :

```
function writeToSheet() {
  var id,options,range,response,sh,ss,url,values;

  id = 'Put the spreadsheet ID here';
  range = "Sheet1!A1:A1";
  values = {values: [['3','two','nine']]}; // Modified

  url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" +
    id + "/values/" + range + ":append?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED";

  options = {
    "method":"post",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    },
    "contentType": "application/json", // Added
    "payload": JSON.stringify(values) // Added
  }

  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options)
  response = JSON.parse(response);

  Logger.log('response ' + JSON.stringify(response))
}
```

#### References :

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)
- [Resource: ValueRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values#ValueRange)

If this didn't work, can I ask you about the error messages? I would like to modify it.

Comment: @Sandy Good Welcome. I'm glad your issue was solved.